# Youtube API V3: Total comments count [Videos]

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get all video comments of a channel. At the moment I'm proceeding like this:

1.) Getting all video ids of a channel (1 quota)
2.) Sending new request with "part: statistics" and getting the total comment count to a youtube video (2 Quota)

It's polling in 30 seconds intervall and I wanted to reduce the quota. Therefore is there a possibility to query whether there are any new comments for a channel videos (Total amount of comments for a channel including channel comments would be fine too)? Like saving the old value of total amount of comments and comparing it with the new amount of the query?

Answer (score 0):

No, from my experience.

I would not use video's `commentCount`.
- you can pull over 260 comments from a video whose comment count is only 243. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87xYGDR_eME`

I would not try optimizing by stopping at recent comments.
- this would work for threads, but each thread has replies. So you have to check each thread anyways just to see if they have new replies.
- **note**: it's dangerous to use commentThreads' reply mode, as it may only return a subset of replies. Instead get a comment list using parentId.

Perhaps, if you sort by time and save the id of comments you've collected, you can use cheap requests like `id` to figure out which comments are new and pull them with `snippet`.
- stop when you get to an `id` you've already gathered.

This may not be simple though because `publishedAt` or `updatedAt` leave two questions:

1. will an old comment be bumped to the top if it's edited? If so, you can't stop once you recognize a comment `id`, because it might have jumped ahead of new comments (unless the change the id when it's edited).
2. will the old comment not be bumped if edited? If this is the case, you need to check `snippet` for each comment as the `textDisplay` may be different. In this case I can see no optimizations.